# MySQL Column ID Number

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am writing a simple `Java` program that connects to a `MySQL` Database. 
The user can choose any of the following options:-

```
1) View the contents of the database
2) Add an entry to the database
3) Remove an entry from the database
```

The problem is that when a user chooses the delete option, there is a prompt asking which row they would like to delete.

If there are 10 rows and the user selects row 5 then this row is
deleted, but when they choose to view the database contents again the
first column ID numbering runs as follows

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

i.e. the numbering is missing 5. I was hoping that after deleting the 5th row that the numbering would move down i.e. go

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Hope this makes sense. Is there a way of the column ID numbering automatically updating?

Comment: Yes. It is called auto-increment. You'll need to configure this in your db.

Comment: Don't use actual id(DB id) at the time of viewing.Take one variable when you iterate through resultset.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any mechanism to automatically renumber the ID after deletion as this is a rather unwanted behaviour. The ID of a database record is usually intended to identify the record independent of its content. So it shouldn't change over time. For more inforamtion see [Persistent Object Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_Object_Identifier)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think mysql do that what are you trying to do.An workaround would be updating the ids after deletion of the row

```
delete from tableName where id=5;
update tableName set id=id-1 where id > 5 order by id;
```

where 5 is the id to be deleted replace 5 in both query with your deletedId variable.